# Create empty disk for Google Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am try to creat a compute instance using Googles deployment manager. It has shall get two disk, one based on a boot image and a second that shall be blank. The blank disk will later on be formated and mounted correctly by salt stack. Deployment manager complains with "Source image must be specified."  How do I create a second blank disk for a compute instance using deployment manager?

My compute-instance.jinja:

```
resources:
- type: compute.v1.instance
  name: {{ env["deployment"] }}-{{ env["name"] }}
  properties:
    zone: europe-west1-c
    machineType: zones/europe-west1-c/machineTypes/n1-standard-1
    disks:
    - deviceName: {{ env["deployment"] }}-{{ env["name"] }}
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        sourceImage: global/images/XXXXXXX
    - deviceName: {{ env["deployment"] }}-{{ env["name"] }}-data
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: false
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        diskSizeGb: {{ properties["size"] }}
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: global/networks/default
      accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by creating a separate resource for the disk using: 

`- type: compute.v1.disk
  name: {{ env["deployment"] }}-{{ env["name"] }}-1-data
  properties:
    sizeGb: {{ properties["size"] }}
    zone: europe-west1-c`

Then refer to it from the compute-instance:

    `- deviceName: {{ env["deployment"] }}-{{ env["name"] }}-1-data
      boot: false
      autoDelete: true
      source: $(ref.{{ env["deployment"] }}-{{ env["name"] }}-1-data.selfLink)`

Comment: Here is the syntax reference: https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/syntax-reference#references](Syntax) and  https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/using-references#replace_the_networks_in_the_virtual_machine_properties_with_references

Answer (score 2):

If you must supply the source image, you can create an image of an empty disk.

The downside of this, is that you will start [paying](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing) (not much tough) for 10gb of image storage when your actually storing nothing.

```
gcloud compute disks create emptydisk --size 10GB
gcloud compute images create empty-disk-image --source-disk emptydisk
```

And then use it as the source image

```
- deviceName: {{ env["deployment"] }}-{{ env["name"] }}-data
  type: PERSISTENT
  boot: false
  autoDelete: true
  initializeParams:
    sourceImage: projects/your-project-id/global/images/empty-disk-image
    diskSizeGb: {{ properties["size"] }}
```